# Overload -> operator to forward member-access through Proxy

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, proxy-pattern

I'm trying to wrap a Python `PyObject*` in an `Object` class.
In Python, everything is a `PyObject*`.
A list is a `PyObject*`, and each item in the list is itself a `PyObject*`.
Which could even be another list.
etc.

I'm trying to allow `fooList[42] = barObj` style syntax by means of a Proxy pattern ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680299/implementing-recursive-proxy-pattern-in-c11)).

Now that I have that working, I want to extend it so that `fooList[42]` can be used as an `Object`. Specifically I want to be able to handle...

```
fooList[42].myObjMethod()
fooList[42].myObjMember = ...
```

`Object` has a lot of methods, and currently `fooList[42].myObjMethod()` is going to first resolve `fooList[42]` into a `Proxy` instance, say `tmpProxy`, and then attempt `tmpProxy.myObjMethod()`.

This means I would have to do

```
void Proxy::myObjMethod(){ return wrapped_ob.myObjMethod(); }
```

i.e. manually relay each of `Object`'s methods through `Proxy`, which is ugly.

I can't see any perfect solution (see the above linked answer), but I would be happy to use:

```
fooList[42]->myObjMethod()
```

... as a compromise, seeing as -> ***can*** be overloaded (as opposed to `.` which cannot).

However, I can't find any documentation for overloading `operator->`.

My best guess is that it must return a pointer to some object (say `pObj`), and C++ will invoke `pObj->whatever`.

---

Below is my attempted implementation. However, I'm running into a *'taking the address of a temporary object of type Object'* warning.

I have, within my `Object` class:

```
const Object operator[] (const Object& key)     const { 
    return Object{ PyObject_GetItem( p, key.p ) }; 
}
```

NOTE that 'const Object&' runs into *'taking the address of a temporary object of type Object'* warning.

```
class Proxy {
private:
    const Object& container;
    const Object& key;

public:
    // at this moment we don't know whether it is 'c[k] = x' or 'x = c[k]'
    Proxy( const Object& c, const Object& k ) : container{c}, key{k}
    { }

    // Rvalue
    // e.g. cout << myList[5] hits 'const Object operator[]'
    operator Object() const {
        return container[key];
    }

    // Lvalue
    // e.g. (something = ) myList[5] = foo
    const Proxy&  operator= (const Object& rhs_ob) {
        PyObject_SetItem( container.p, key.p, rhs_ob.p );
        return *this; // allow daisy-chaining a = b = c etc, that's why we return const Object&
    }

    const Object* operator->() const { return &container[key]; }
    // ^ ERROR: taking the address of a temporary object of type Object
};
```

The idea is to allow `myList[5]->someMemberObj = ...` style syntax.

`myList[5]` resolves as a `Proxy` instance, which is wrapping an `Object` (the sixth element of `myList`). Let's call it `myItem`.

Now I want `someProxy->fooFunc()` or `someProxy->fooProperty` to invoke `myItem.fooFunc()` or `myItem.fooProperty` respectively.

I'm running into a *'taking the address of a temporary object of type Object'* warning.

Comment: To add to Jarod42's answer i find this table to be very usefull: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: I realise that my original title didn't match the question. Hence I've adjusted the title, and re-asked an appropriate question for the original title [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690419/how-to-overload-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can change `Object`, you may add

```
class Object {
public:
    // other code
    const Object* operator -> () const { return this; }
    Object* operator -> () { return this; }
};
```

And for your `Proxy`

```
Object operator->() { return container[key]; }
```

So, for example

```
myObj[42]->myFoo = ...
```

is mostly equivalent to

```
Proxy proxy = myObj[42];
Object obj = proxy.operator ->();
Object* pobj = obj.operator ->(); // so pobj = &obj;
pobj->myFoo = ...
```

Comment: Otherwise, you can use the same trick with a second proxy type (that stores an object by value).

Comment: Thanks Jarod42, might you care to explain why this works? For example, what happens exactly when e.g. `myObj[42]->myFoo = ...` is encountered? I can't see whether extra temporary objects might be getting created.

Comment: @Pi: `operator ->` should return something to apply `->` (with chaining possible, as in the current solution). Example added.

Answer (score 2):

I find the `Proxy` class that you wrote as an example a bit confusing so i took the liberty to change it a little:
Here is a simple example:

```
//object with lots of members:
class my_obj
{
public:
    std::string     m_text;

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << m_text << std::endl;
    }
    void bar(std::string t)
    {
        m_text = t;
    }
};
//proxy object
class proxy_class
{
private:
    friend class CustomContainer;
    my_obj* px;

    proxy_class(my_obj * obj_px)
        :px(obj_px)
    {
    }
    proxy_class() = delete;
    proxy_class(const proxy_class &) = delete;
    proxy_class& operator =(const proxy_class &) = delete;
public:

    my_obj* operator ->()
    {
        return px;
    }
};
//custom container that is the only one that can return proxy objects
class CustomContainer
{
public:
    std::map<std::size_t, my_obj> stuff;

    proxy_class     operator [](const std::size_t index)
    {
        return proxy_class(&stuff[index]);
    }
};
```

example usage:

```
CustomContainer cc;
cc[0]->foo();
cc[0]->bar("hello world");
cc[0]->foo();
```

As a design consideration the proxy class should be create in a controlled environment so constructors are removed from preventing miss-usage.

`CustomContainer` has to only return `proxy_class` with a reference to `my_obj` so it can use anything, `std::map`, `std::vector`, etc

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of coaxing coliru, I have a working testcase.

Please refer to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75237/c11-proxy-pattern-for-supporting-obidx-someobjmember-type-acc

Many thanks to Jarod, for supplying the correct syntax and understanding for -> overload.