# How to overload -> operator in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

As per the title, how to overload -> operator in C++?

I can't find any documentation.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) glosses over it.

The [Wikipedia page on overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) similarly glosses over it.

[Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) <-- this SO post again has a '->' shaped hole in it, although [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading#comment5687557_4421719) gives a hint:

> operator->() is actually extremely weird. It's not required to return
>   a value_type* -- in fact, it can return another class type, provided
>   that class type has an operator->(), which will then be called
>   subsequently. This recursive calling of operator->()s proceeds until a
>   value_type* return type occurs. Madness! :)

It appears that this particular operator is not straightforward to overload.

Could someone link to documentation, or (preferably) provide some here?

PS I recognisze this is an unusual overload, I have need of it in a Proxy pattern, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689105/how-to-overload-operator-in-c-proxy-pattern)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here.  You overload it much like anything else.  It just has a few extra constraints.

Comment: And what are these extra constraints? Where are they documented? That is the issue!

Comment: I think it is explained very well in the top answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777845/overloading-member-access-operators-c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67868/discussion-between-p-i-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: **Moderator Note:** I've removed the unnecessary comments here. If you feel the need to continue this discussion, then take it to chat.